# Selecting smart plug

Tags: smart-switch

I'm about to buy a smart plug to monitor consumption of an electric heater.

My key objective is to have a plug measuring consumption and being able to read it from a smart phone, as raw as possible (ideally at least hourly resolution).

In my region I found Hama, Tp Link (Tapo P100) and Xiaomi (Mi Smart Plug Wifi) models at similar prices.

Do anybody have experience with those? How user friendly is their app? Is it possible to download raw data?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about home improvement within the scope defined in the [help].

Answer (score 5):

Two very important **safety** things to consider:

#### Certification

Electrical devices *should*, in general, be tested and certified by an independent laboratory. The two that come to mind, at least for the US, are [UL](https://www.ul.com/) and [ETL](https://www.intertek.com/marks/etl/). There are some others, but not every acronym indicates testing/certification.

While in theory this is an issue with "anything you plug in", it is really important on a device that is (a) plugged in and unattended for long periods of time and/or (b) has large currents passing through it (because a bad connection or poor design might generate a little bit of heat with a little current and not cause a serious problem, but the same bad connection or poor design with a *lot* of current can start a fire). **An energy monitor for a heater has both of these concerns.**

#### Current/Power Capacity

Many devices are not designed to handle a full 15A or 20A circuit. In particular, timers, motion detectors, dimmers and smart switches will often have a limit. Sometimes that limit is a single absolute number (in W or A) and sometimes it varies depending on the type of load (resistive/incandescent lighting vs. fluorescent vs. LED vs. motor). A simple *monitor* is likely to support the full capacity of a circuit, but anything that *switches* has to have a relay or other circuitry capable of handling the full current and may have a lower limit. Residential lighting, in particular, typically uses a few hundred watts in a room with incandescent lights and far less with LEDs, so many devices are designed with lower capacity because saving $ 1 per device x thousands of devices = significant profit for the manufacturer.

Typical heaters are designed (in the US) to handle 15A x 125V x 0.8 = 1,500W. So unless your heater indicates something else, that is the *minimum* value you should be looking for in any switch or monitoring device.

Comment: This is an exceptionally good answer to what is, essentially, a shopping question. +2 if I could!

Answer (score 1):

This goes way outside what we handle here on Home Improvement, but I found that ESP8266-based smart plugs can run custom firmwares that can inspect power consumption and serve via API. Shelly is a popular brand of ESP2866 smart plug and Tasmota is a popular firmware.

This is beyond most users, but Smarthome tinkerers will be familiar with MQTT configuration, some PHP and APIs that are mentioned in [this article](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2021/using-shelly-plug-monitor-starlinks-power-consumption).

But like I said, this isn't really what we do here, so this question is likely to be closed.